# JavaScript Method results in Non Secure Item IE6

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, ssl, https

So I am baffled by this one. I have a function that is responsible for a non-secure item warning message to appear when viewing my web page from with IE6 on SSL. If I comment out the entire function the message goes way. If I just comment out the one method call it remains. What is really driving me nuts is if I remove all of the logic from within the method.... the message remains???!!! I literally have to comment out the whole method including the signature. The method contains JQuery library logic but I don't see why that would matter when all of the function logic is commented except for the signature. Has anyone seen this before?

Here is the function:

```
function styleNavigationCorners() {
        if (!($.browser.msie && $.browser.version.substr(0, 1) == '6')) {
            $(".DecisionPointTitle").corner({
                tl: { radius: 8 },
                tr: { radius: 8 },
                bl: { radius: 8 },
                br: { radius: 8 },
                antiAlias: true,
                autoPad: false
            });
            $(".DecisionPointHeadline").corner({
                tl: { radius: 8 },
                tr: { radius: 8 },
                bl: false,
                br: false,
                antiAlias: true,
                autoPad: false
            });
            $("#NavigationFooter").corner({
                bl: { radius: 8 },
                br: { radius: 8 },
                tl: false,
                tr: false,
                antiAlias: true,
                autoPad: false
            });
        }

    }
```

This still gives me the non-secure warning? :

```
   function styleNavigationCorners() {
//            if (!($.browser.msie && $.browser.version.substr(0, 1) == '6')) {
//                $(".DecisionPointTitle").corner({
//                    tl: { radius: 8 },
//                    tr: { radius: 8 },
//                    bl: { radius: 8 },
//                    br: { radius: 8 },
//                    antiAlias: true,
//                    autoPad: false
//                });
//                $(".DecisionPointHeadline").corner({
//                    tl: { radius: 8 },
//                    tr: { radius: 8 },
//                    bl: false,
//                    br: false,
//                    antiAlias: true,
//                    autoPad: false
//                });
//                $("#NavigationFooter").corner({
//                    bl: { radius: 8 },
//                    br: { radius: 8 },
//                    tl: false,
//                    tr: false,
//                    antiAlias: true,
//                    autoPad: false
//                });
//            }

        }
```

I have searched for duplicate function signatures have found none. Can anyone help? Thanks!

-Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can I assume you are using the [curvy corners jquery wrap](http://www.aspcode.net/JQuery-Curvy-Corners.aspx)?
If so then you will find the following issue with that library. It runs the following on ie6

```
  document.write("<script id='__ie_onload' defer='defer' src='javascript:void(0)'><\/script>");
```

Setting the src to void will cause the non secure warning. IIRC you could try changing this to javascript:false - again another hack or even include a blank file on the server and point to that to avoid the warning for sure. Whatever you opt for youll have to change the source library.

Just as an aside - Do you really need those corners? 26k minified of js is a hefty price to pay!

Comment: Yes.. I need to corners. The library did contain this IFrame... changing the src to javascript:false; was the answer.

Comment: I'm using HTTPS, and **src=javascript:false** did not work for me. The error remained. Instead I used **src=//0** or **src=https:javascript:false** .

Answer (score 3):

IE6 contains a bug here.

JavaScript-protocol URIs are treated as insecure, and this results in a mixed content warning when they are encountered.  See my answer here: [How To Tell What Files IE Thinks Are "nonsecure"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96382/how-to-tell-what-files-ie-thinks-are-nonsecure/1022020#1022020) for a tool that will help you verify that it's the JavaScript-protocol URI causing the issue.

Comment: in the case of the above issue fiddler would not help I believe

Comment: No, but the ScriptFree tool I mentioned in my response will.

Comment: Ah sorry, I saw your name and instant thought fiddler!

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same SSL error with no HTTP calls for resources.  Found a javascript(void) in the code 5 times, and this was it as the error went away when I removed those pieces.  Just to let you all know what worked for me to keep the pieces and rid the error...

=//0 did not work because it would try and take the user to a page 0.0.0.0

=https:javascript:false did not work because it tried to take the user to a page and got a 404.

For me, I didn't really need the href since I was using the < a > with an onclick command to get it to show or hide different sections of a footer.  Here's what I had to change my code to.

```
    <li id="li_MainMenu"    class="li_click on" title="Categories" onclick="showHide(this.getAttribute('id').replace( 'li_', '')); onOff(this.getAttribute('id'));"><a href="javascript(void);">Why Factory Bunk Beds </a></li>
```

was changed to:

```
    <li id="li_MainMenu"    class="li_click on" title="Categories" onclick="showHide(this.getAttribute('id').replace( 'li_', '')); onOff(this.getAttribute('id'));"><a>Why Factory Bunk Beds </a></li>
```

I simply removed the:

```
    href="javascript(void);"
```

from the  tag and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Is this inside a script tag?  Or is the script included with the src attribute?  If it is inside the script tag, I have no clue why it would be doing that.

Also, can you give us a link to this page?

---

Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://path/to/file"></script>
```

Comment: This script is in a external js file which is getting include via a src attribute. No.. unfortunately the page is not publicly hosted.

Comment: If it is an external file, try forcing IE6 to use HTTPS by including the protocol and the full path name to the file: i.e. "https: //path/to/file" (note that the space is there to force the comment to not turn it into a link)