# Page contains both secure and nonsecure items

Tags: asp.net, html, internet-explorer-6

I'm working on a legacy web application - frames and a mixture of html, asp and aspx.  The entire site is https.

For some strange reason when I hit a specific page I get the magic message that says the Page contains both secure and nonsecure items.  (IE obviously doesn't want to tell me what those resources are)  I have checked the page that's being loaded and there are absolutely no http://... links - everything is relative links.  I have fired up fiddler and checked what's being requested - everything looks fine.

I am completely at wit's end here.  I have absolutely no idea why I'm getting this message, but it's completely screwing with the site.

How do I track down the underlying cause?

Comment: are you using any flash, that in turn is loading up in-secure resources?

Comment: do you have any iframes (even ones created as a shim for IE6 z-index issues) that have a src (initial or permanent) of `about:blank`? IIRC, this originally tripped IE up into categorizing the frame as being insecure.

Comment: EricLaw has another tool that may reveal the url... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96382/how-to-tell-what-files-ie-thinks-are-nonsecure/1022020#1022020

Comment: Scunliffe - I only have 1 frame, and that frame definitely does have a src.  However when I run Eric's tool I get a message saying it stopped on about:blank...

Comment: Does that frame src get set right away? or is it loaded without a src, then updated later?

Comment: No it is set right away.  The thing that I don't get is that all pages work except for this one page.

Comment: Does this only happen in IE6? Have you seen it happen in other versions of Explorer or other browsers?

Comment: @Spudley: Tried it on IE6, Chrome and Firefox.  I don't an error message on Chrome or Firefox, but the frame doesn't render correctly.

Comment: any chance there is a public url we can hit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some ideas:

1. Do you have an iframe which is set to load the "about:blank" URL rather than an actual blank HTML page. IE will see about: url as not being part of the secure site.
2. Are you using any IE hacks which involve the CSS "behavior" style? This is an MSIE-specific feature which is used by a number of hacks to get IE to be more compatible with modern standards. They load HTC files, but there are some quirks and unusual rules around how IE handles them with respect to the rest of the page environment.
3. Do you have an third-party stats apps on your site (google analytics, etc)? Have you checked that they are loading via https?
4. Do you have any Javascript or CSS which includes subsequent files?
5. Have you tried it in other browsers which might have better tools for analysing the site than IE6? (IE8 has a very handy 'Developer Tools' feature, though I still think Firefox + Firebug is the best browser debug tool available)

Comment: Finally realized I have a CSS file which loads resources which don't exist.  The weird thing is when I hit the page directly IE doesn't report an error, but when I redirect back to the page it does.  Any idea why this happens?  Also, Fiddler didn't report that the resources don't exist.  I'm rather confused.

Comment: I can't give a difinitive answer to that! But IE is particularly good at producing weird results like that. My guess is that there's a difference in how IE handles direct 404 errors and cached ones. Maybe if it knows a request is going to give a 404 error, it doesn't bother trying to load it again, and just goes to about:blank or something like that? But as I say, I can't really be sure what's going on there. Glad you solved it though.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any hidden frames loading pages for some data transfer - check they aren't getting a 404 as this will trigger IE to see and `http` request.

Comment: I've checked that there are no 404's in fiddler.  Actually, only 404 is for favicon.ico, but that can't be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using a tool like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) or [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) it should be possible to see all traffic and detect the problem. I actually had a similar issue a while back and mine was caused my a minified version of prototype/scriptaculous i was using so it could be worth trying to remove any javascript and go from there if nothing else is apparent.

Comment: Did you read this bit? "I have fired up fiddler and checked what's being requested - everything looks fine."

Comment: @Jaco - no idea how i missed that, sorry. Fiddler should help but as i mentioned above it didnt actually help me. It seems the problem is often javascript related. Have you tried checking if the error still appears with JS disabled?

Comment: I disabled JavaScript and still got the same issue