# IE7: This page contains both secure and nonsecure items

Tags: internet-explorer, ssl, https

I've searched far and wide for suggestions and solutions to this problem, but I'm still stuck.

I have a few pages on my website (using SSL) that are presenting this error. I've used various debugging tools (Google Dev Tools, Fiddler 2) to ensure that I am not loading any non-SSL objects (images, css, javascript). Also I have no iFrames so that is not a concern.

Everything is loading using HTTPS, however this error keeps popping up. And given that it's an eCommerce site, I can basically forget about anyone using IE7 to buy products.

The page is https://www.hottubcoverscanada.ca/build/step1.php?product=859

A page that works on the site error-free is https://www.hottubcoverscanada.ca/

I'm looking forward to hearing anyone's suggestions
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IE7 has a known bug when you dynamically (with Javascript) change the styling of elements on your page and use CSS attributes with relative URLs (e.g. to set a background image). If you specify a relative URL, IE7 will correctly load the image using SSL but still complain that the page contains nonsecure items.

From what I can see, the file jquery.lightbox-0.5.js could be causing the problems. It contains several relative URLs in the settings which later are used to set the background of elements.

Comment: This is likely correct. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96382/how-to-tell-what-files-ie-thinks-are-nonsecure/1022020#1022020 for a way to confirm.

Comment: In my case it was a data-uri in a css file, another weird error I guess: http://www.gallagherwebsitedesign.com/blog/ie7-ie6-url-data-nonsecure-items